Possible null reference warning when using getter and setters
I am confused about why I am getting a Null Reference warning when my setter is assigning to a nullable value, and my getter is returning a non null value.
Here is my code for my object:
public class LocationSensor
{
    private string? _contextualUnits;
    public string? UniqueUnits { get; set; }
    public string GeneralUnits { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// This field is meant to embody the units based on the user viewing them. If this sensor
    /// has a unique unit, that is always taken. If not, we check to see if the application has
    /// specified a contextual unit based on the users chosen measurement system. If that is not specified,
    /// we default to the general units (usually the metric system).
    /// </summary>
    public string ContextualUnits
    {
        get { return UniqueUnits ?? _contextualUnits ?? GeneralUnits; }
        set { _contextualUnits = value; }
    }
    public string? ImperialUnits { get; set; }
}

And here is the code where I assign a value to _contextualUnits.
public async Task<LocationSensor> GetLocationSensorAsync(int sensorId, int locationId, bool? inMetric = null)
{
    LocationSensor locationSensor = await _locationSensorRepository.GetLocationSensorAsync(sensorId, locationId);
    if (inMetric != null)
    {
        locationSensor.ContextualUnits = inMetric.Value ? locationSensor.GeneralUnits : locationSensor.ImperialUnits;
    }
    return locationSensor;
}

Given I am assigning a possibly null value to a nullable private field, why am I being given a "possible null reference assignment" warning on this line ls.ContextualUnits = inMetric.Value ? ls.GeneralUnits : ls.ImperialUnits;.

Given I am assigning a possibly null value to a nullable private field - you aren't. You are assigning a potentially null value to the property ContextualUnits that is non-nullable. That inside of that property you only assign to nullable private storage is not relevant for the analysis of the use of ContextualUnits.

Let's look at a much more simplified version of your code:
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string? newValue = null;
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        c.MyProperty = newValue;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private string? _backingField;
    public string MyProperty 
    {
        get => _backingField ?? "default";
        set => _backingField = value;
    }   
}

= newValue; has the same warning: "Possible null reference assignment".
You've instructed the compiler (because you have the Nullable Reference Types feature enabled) that the MyProperty property should not accept null values. That's exactly why it's informing you that a null assignment (= newValue;) is against your wishes.
The fact that, under the hood, the property gets and sets to a nullable string doesn't matter. The public contract states that the property shouldn't accept null. How the property is implemented isn't relevant to enforcing that desire.

In your code, the problem is that, because of the ternary operator, you could be assigning ls.ImperialUnits (nullable string) to locationSensor.ContextualUnits (non-nullable string).

I see. So although there is a warning, there is no possibility of a null reference given the getter will always return a string?

In my example, _backingField ?? "default" cannot return null because the last entry is impossible to be null. However, even a non-null string data type can still contain null. https://dotnetfiddle.net/0qyqbn The more you ignore nullable warnings or bypass them with !, the faster you will find yourself in a situation where a value that says it's non-nullable actually contains a null value.

@kj49 The getter is not even a part of the question, the confirmation of its non-nullability comes from how its body null-checks against the property declaration, not from what you are doing in the setter. The compiler is warning you that in the setter your value will be null when you don't expect it, not that the same null will be later returned from the getter.
